# Hijacking NSIS's download file on Windows

Tags: nsis, fiddler, web.py, session-hijacking

There's a file that I know it's packed with NSIS,and the logic of download file and then Exec highly possible using the NSIS functions like ExecWait in NSIS,

The Problem is :

I'm try to replace the file that NSIS downloaded from web so I could do some tests, first I changed the hosts and made a http server with web.py,so the original url hijacked to myself server and I put a redirect download file link with,and on server I saw 200 but in the client I use some tool find out it returning 400.(I direct print the url in a browser and it worked well download the hijacked file) I don't know what's wrong.

web.py Codes

```
def GET(self, name):
    raise web.redirect('/static/test.exe')
```

Logs 4 the file download

```
GET     302     240       Redirect url1,url2
GET     302     300       Redirec  url2,url3
GET     200     1.27 M    application/octet-stream url3
```

So I want to know

1. what may cause the problem of 400 code,even in my python webpy server it showed 200? (sry I'm not familiar with http)
2. anyone familiar with NSIS,Is there some other solution I could do this hijack? I've tried with R3 hook,But seems failed,since I don't know with API to hook.
3. In the past I heard of Fiddler could help me with my task,But that traffic just don't show in Fiddler,Maybe The NSis download Fiddler can't capture? And with HttpAnalyze I could see that traffic(the log upon),but I can't do what I want,So Is there any other tool could feed my needs(maybe Made a rule with when xxurl then replace it with myurl)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different download plug-ins for NSIS, some are custom HTTP clients and some use [WinINet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383630(v=vs.85).aspx).

The two most popular plug-ins are NSISdl and [INetC](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Inetc_plug-in). NSISdl is a custom HTTP client but it should support 301 and 302 redirects and INetC uses WinINet and should work if Internet Explorer works.

I would suggest that you just redirect the domain name to 127.0.0.1 in your [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) and run a [simple HTTP file server](http://www.pablosoftwaresolutions.com/html/baby_web_server.html) locally without any kind of redirection, just recreate the required folder structure and use the filename requested by the installer. If that works then you might have to use [WireShark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) to figure out why the redirect fails...

Answer (score 0):

@Anders give me some good advices.But since the url is not static(\xx.exe xx is random),so I can't made a local path same as the Url folder structure :(

Finally I find out it may dued to Http header in past web.py response.
I was wrong to direcly redirect to a static file on webpy server
 `web.redirect('/static/test.exe')`,even in the past  I could download it in browser.but it's header may not feeds original exe needs.

Here's my Solution

Redirect the domain name to 127.0.0.1 in hosts file and run a simple HTTP file server locally.Then still using web.py but change the redirect with

`web.HTTPError('301', {'Location': 'http://myfileurl'})`

And It worked :)